# How can I use nativescript-social-share plugin on modal view?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I used **nativescript-social-share** on **view** It works perfect without any problem. but when I use **nativescript-social-share** on **modal view** It has a problem, share dialog not showed. Does anyone know why this happen ? How can I correct it ?

Comment: Are you using a Frame on your modal page?

Comment: No, I'm not using Frame on modal page.

Comment: The plugin uses the topmost frame to present the dialog, as you are not using a frame in modal view it would pick the frame for previous page that is behind the modal view. Try using a frame, that might solve the issue.